# Rails: Twitter Omniauth - OmniAuth::NoSessionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I am using the `omniauth-twitter` gem and keep running into this issue:

`(twitter) Authentication failure! session_expired: OmniAuth::NoSessionError, Session Expired`

This *only* happens on the staging and production servers (can't re-produce it locally).

Gemfile:

`gem 'omniauth-twitter'`

Here is my controller that handles the request:
https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/72fcdc04eeb545b0b473

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @unclesol - I think it was something to do with my API keys